# VS 2013 does not compile new code after saving

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've been using VS 2013 at school to write simple code for c++. After I save the code using "Save As" and compiling the code, it runs fine. The problem is when I add some new code and compile it does not take the new code that's been added. It will just run the code from the point I save it no matter the changes that I make. If I exit VS and re-open the project/solution it will compile and run any changes before I "save as". I've searched(probably not in the right way), I've asked students around me, and I've even asked the instructor(stick up his bum) but no answers.

addition info: ive been saving to my thumb drive.()

Comment: maybe you have not included the file you "saved as" in the project, but some older version with another name or in another directory?

Comment: Visual Studio will only compile what is there in solution. Say abc.cpp xyz.cpp etc.. Seems you are saving in different name with "save as.." option. So please add that file in your project and compile. But make sure if both similar files included in project then you may get redefinition error..